# How to write SELECT query in mysql json Array data

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I am trying to get the email from the array json, but it returns null value

```
[
    {
        "name": "Arun", 
        "email": "arun@arun.com"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Arun kumar",
        "email": "arunkumar@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

and my Json query is `select json->>"$.name" as email from json`

But this query is return null value

Comment: what kind of syntax it is `select json->>"$.name" as email from json`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie its mysql json select query

Comment: what about json_decode()?

Comment: you want to fetch name or email in other words Arun or arun@arun.com?

Comment: @ArunRanga, In order to use JSON type in MySQL you must have your MySQL version >= 8.x. Search something in this JSON is very complicated and sometimes not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following and worked for me on your json sample

```
$json='[{"name": "Arun", "email": "arun@arun.com"}, {"name": "Arun kumar", "email": "arunkumar@gmail.com"}]';
$data=json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["email"] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work,

`JSON_EXTRACT(yourstring, '$[*].email')`

yourstring - your json data or field in database
`$` is json syntax to search json object
`*` means all multidimensional array
`email` check email in * values